# Cannot Bring Modal to Front

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem where the Modal Bootstrap doesn't go to the front of the modal backdrop. As shown in the Code snippet, when the user presses "Deploy", the modal pops up. In my version, the modal is in the "back" where I cannot interact with the Send and Cancel buttons. I looked meticulously and it is because of a "min.css" file in my project. How can I override it such that I am able to interact with the buttons in the modal? I tried z-index but that didn't work.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal-content {

  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #89f7fe 0%, #66a6ff 60%, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
  margin:auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
   animation-name: animatetop;
   animation-duration: 0.4s

}

.modal{
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

}

.modal2-content {
  background: white;
  margin:auto;
  width: 500px;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
   animation-name: animatetop;
   animation-duration: 0.4s

}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"/>
  <!-- <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

  <link href="css/couponsexample.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>

 <body id="page-top">
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div id="content">
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="card shadow mb-4">
       <div class="card-header py-3">
        <span style="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end; width:100%; padding:0;">
         <button class="buttonTest" id="myBtn">New Discount</button>
        </span>
       </div>

       <div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
         <div class="modal2-content">
          <div style="background-color:#1E90FF" class="modal-header">
           <font color="white">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Deployment</h4>
           </font>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <p>Please confirm that the deployed coupon is accurate and ready. Once deployed, you cannot retake the coupon until it expires. Canceling will cause problems Test Test Tes</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="card-body">
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
         <div class="modal-content" >
          <form id="msform">
           <span class="close">&times;</span>
           <fieldset>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 4</h3>
           </fieldset>
          </form>
         </div>
        </div>
        <section>
         <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col s12 m6">
            <div class="card">
             <span>
              <a href="#" class="buttonDeploy" style="position: absolute; right: 12px; top:5px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal">Deploy</a>
             </span>
             <div class="card-content">
              <span class="card-title blue-text text-darken-2"  style="white-space: nowrap">$5.00 Discount</span>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </section>
       </div>

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"/>
  <script src="couponsjs.js"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Which modal is in front of what?  What modal can you not see?

Comment: The Modal Bootsrap Dialogue box-I cannot interact with the buttons. How can I force it to be in the front so I can interact with the buttons and dialogue box?

Comment: So you can see the buttons, but the backdrop is in the way?

Comment: Correct-I can see the buttons but backdrop causes them to not be able to be interacted. The entire bootstrap modal is being interrupted by backdrop. I was wonder if theres a way to "force" it to the front of backdrop.

Comment: I've also added a picture of the situation in my original post

Comment: I am just trying to re-create your code to see if I can find the issue

Comment: Thanks jae.phoenix- I believe the min.css is causing the problem since when I delete it, it works but I need that in there. The file is pretty long.

Comment: The min.css file is located here:https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/blob/master/css/sb-admin-2.min.css

Comment: Is that your project?

Comment: No its not I just used their template for some of the functions on the webpage. the css.min is whats causing the problem but its a large file